# Make a div disappear after clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made circle divs fall randomly. When I click on a circle, I want it to disappear and I want the score to be incremented by one.

Here is my code:

```js
function CreateDiv() {
    var ranLeft1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 700) + 1);
    var ranInterval = 1000 + Math.floor((Math.random() * 5000) + 1);
    jQuery('<div class="droper1" id="droper1" onclick="myFunction()" />').css({top: 20, left: ranLeft1 }).animate({top: "+=573px"}, 9000 ).appendTo('#container' );
    window.setTimeout( CreateDiv, ranInterval );
}

var score = 0;
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
    score++;
    //make the div dissapear after one click on it .. how ??!!
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that you want them removed from the DOM, not just simply disappeared, right?  Otherwise your DOM is going to get really full, really fast!

Comment: It seems that you will create several divs with the same id `droper1`. That's invalid!

Comment: Why the downvote?  It's a valid question and he's posted code that he has tried.

Comment: As scottie said, you should remove the element to prevent the DOM from getting full and having the browser lag/crash. You should also be sure to do this to circles that fall outside of the view and are not clicked. Maybe you could create an interval where you check the `top` attribute of each circle and remove it if it is past a certain value

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (note: this is from memory and untested)

```
function CreateDiv() {
    var ranLeft1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 700) + 1);
    var ranInterval = 1000 + Math.floor((Math.random() * 5000) + 1);
    jQuery('<div class="droper1" onclick="myFunction()" />').css({top: 20, left: ranLeft1 }).animate({top: "+=573px"}, 9000 ).appendTo('#container' );
    window.setTimeout( CreateDiv, ranInterval );
}

var score = 0;

$(document).on("click", ".droper1", function() {
    score++;
    $("#score").innerHtml(score);
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to `remove()` `$(this)` when it's clicked, but using delegation is faster than assigning the click method directly to each newly-generated div:

```
var div_counter=0;
function CreateDiv() {
    var ranLeft1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 700) + 1);
    var ranInterval = 1000 + Math.floor((Math.random() * 5000) + 1);
    jQuery('<div class="droper1" id="'+ ++div_counter +'" />').css({top: 20, left: ranLeft1 }).animate({top: "+=573px"}, 9000 ).appendTo('#container' );
    window.setTimeout( CreateDiv, ranInterval );
}

var score = 0;

$('body').on('click', '.droper1', function(){
   score++;
   $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: `div_counter` helps you have uniqie `id`s; though you can remove the attribute entirely if you won't be using it elsewhere.

Comment: Looks like @Scottie gave you basically the same answer, already.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you desire Memo Awaw.

> When I click on a circle, I want it to disappear and I want the score
>   to be incremented by one.

The below code on load creates a click function.  On click of one of the circles, the div is removed (but you could also use hide if you wanted). The score is incremented by one. For testing reasons I left in a console.log() so you could optionally see your score get incremented in the inspector.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var score = 0;
  $('.foo').on('click', function() {
    jQuery(this).remove();
    score++;
    console.log("New score is: " + score);
  });

});
```

```css
.foo {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-indent: -10000px;
}
.foo:hover {
  cursor: crosshair;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='foo' id=1>content</div>
<div class='foo' id=2>content</div>
<div class='foo' id=3>content</div>
<div class='foo' id=4>content</div>
```

Comment: You should change this `jQuery(this).hide();` to this `jQuery(this).remove();`

Comment: Thanks @Joe Sager, I made my code snippet really fast before some other comments about if hide or remove was wanted. I've edited the snippet. Hopefully it helps someone.

Comment: This seem to answer the OP's question, not sure why this was downvoted?

Comment: See comment by Scottie: "This won't work on a dynamically added DOM element. You need to use .on instead of .click"

Comment: @JoeSager Edited to use .on()

Answer (score -2):

```
$('#myBtn').on('click', function(){
     $('droper1').hide();
});
```

Comment: This won't work on a dynamically added DOM element.  You need to use .on instead of .click.

Comment: Also, you would need $('.droper1'), not $('droper1').  This example won't work.